# I am trying to use color package in react native app but it throws the following error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo, yarnpkg

```
./node_modules/color/index.js 257:26
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (257:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|               for (const [i, element] of rgb.entries()) {
|                       const chan = element / 255;
>                       lum[i] = (chan <= 0.039_28) ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;
|               }
```